# Цикл постепенно загружает процессор и оперативку, python

Tags: python

У меня есть скрипт который стоит на VPS сервере. Он работает через selenium, ищет xpath элементы на сайте и сообщает мне в телеграмм если есть какие-то изменения.Этот весь код зациклен через While True. При первом запуске он занимает примерно 30 Мб оперативной памяти и 1-5% ресурсов процессора. Но со временем эти значения увеличиваются, и через часов 5 беспрерывной работы могут достигать уже 150 Мб и 10-15% ЦП. Приходиться перезапускать программу чтобы очистить память. Вопрос таков, возможно ли как-то очищать память в самом коде, чтобы не приходилось каждый раз перезапускать код, или может другие способы есть. Подскажите пожалуйста, я в этой теме еще новичок.

Часть кода:

```
import lxml.html
import telebot
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
import re

executable_path = "A:\Programs\chromedriver.exe"

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_extension('A:\Programs\j.crx')
chrome_options.add_extension('A:\Programs\u.crx')
chrome_options.add_extension('A:\Programs\o.crx')

webdriver = webdriver.Chrome(
    executable_path=executable_path,
    chrome_options=chrome_options
)
timec = input()
webdriver.get('https://site.com/login/')

tyu = webdriver.find_element_by_xpath("")
tyu.send_keys("login")

tye = webdriver.find_element_by_xpath("")
tye.send_keys("password")

ghg = webdriver.find_element_by_xpath("").click()
timec = input()

while True:
    listtt = [70, 85, 54, 58]
    bot = telebot.TeleBot("")
    webdriver.get('https://site.com')
    time.sleep(1.5)
    try:
        a = webdriver.find_element_by_xpath("")
        b = a.text
        ccc = b.replace("", "")
        bhg = int(ccc)
        if bhg in (listtt):
            bot.send_message("")
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: Вы бы код привели, мы ведь не знаем, как это у Вас там реализовано.

Comment: @Михаил Муругов Добавил код

Comment: Можно попробовать сборщик мусора вызывать скриптом: https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html#gc.collect . `PS.` советую форматировать код, а то читать неприятно :) Не нужно экономить место в коде таким способом

Comment: @gil9red а стоит вообще экономить место в коде?

Comment: @SKIP, подловили на слове :) нет, не стоит экономить, форматирование и рефакторинг хорошие друзья программиста